# What are the statistic for the percentage of illegitimate baby in US?

Tags: dataset

Is there a way to know that? Is this a good stackexchange to ask?

Basically I am looking at the number of children within marriage whose biological dad is not the mother's husband during conception.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @JimThio. This question is off-topic for CV (see our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq)). Unfortunately, "statistics" has 2 meanings: 1 of which is "representative numbers" (that's what you're thinking about), & another is "the normative analysis of data" (which is what CV is about).

Comment: Dear Jim, unfortunately this question *is* off-topic for this site. (There are several discussions on meta about this; [here's one](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1298/2970).) The CDC has [some data on unmarried childbearing](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/unmarry.htm) in the U.S. The Census Bureau may collect such info, too.

Comment: Although there is a proposal on Area 51 for a Stack Exchange site that would cover questions of this nature: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37195/data?referrer=MM0IewN_HrmFRGSmvGLajg2

Comment: @Corone: (+1) Thanks for mentioning this! I meant to do so in my previous comment, but must have gotten distracted in the meantime.

Comment: Is there any way to migrate this question to the Data proposal?

Comment: @StasK: Not that I know of, but I'd encourage either Jim or someone following that proposal to post it as an example question. It seems to fit right in to their desired scope.

Comment: Have added it to Data:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37195/data/51477#51477

Comment: Okay thanks. Sorry. I sort of know that it's not related by looking at the other questions here. However, it's statistic stackexchange and I don't know where else to ask.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to figure this out using some of the large scale US population surveys, such as:

- American Community Survey (http://www.census.gov/acs/www/)
- National Survey of Family Growth (http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nsfg.htm)
- National Survey of Children's Health (http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/slaits/nsch.htm)

I would not expect to be able to find the immediate answer in the pre-canned tables. You would need to download the microdata and analyze them in a statistical package (such as Stata which you originally tagged).